# q not accessible access denied windows 7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office

I have an **extra Q drive** created in my windows 7 PC.
I can neither open it nor delete the drive as admin user. Most of the blogs say that this is due to Office Click-to-Run product installation. Apparently the blogs says its a virtual drive that is created which does not consume any hard disk space. I have tried a few ways to remove this drive but no success.
Can anybody provide a solution as to how to get rid of this drive?
Thanks

Comment: We need more information.  This drive could be anything.  For instance my printer creates a storage device on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this issue is found when we use Microsoft Click-to-Run to install Microsoft Office. It is said that this drive is necessary for suck installation and it cannot be accessed.
More details on this is available in the following link:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982434

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide the drive from explorer there is a registry hack described in this forum thread:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/local-disk-q-access-denied-0-bytes-file-system/f4426199-5077-4bbc-99f5-49036b73478d

The steps are:

> Start Menu >> Run and type regedit and press Enter Navigate to the
>   following path:
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
>
> (If Explorer is not here, you can right click and select new key and
>   enter Explorer to create key Explorer as image below.)
>   Right click New DWORD (32-bits) value:
>
> Value Name: NoDrives
>
> Value Data (Decimal): 65536
>
> Restart your machine to apply changes and see your work.